# Outlook 365 Administration: How to grant Required scope Mail.ReadWrite to email account

Tags: ms-office

How does an Office 365 administrator grant permissions for an email account to be accessed via the REST API? To be more specific: to grant the "Required Scope"

The Office 365 administrator at the company I work for and myself were on the phone for at least an hour with the people at mssupport_microsoft_com attempting to find an answer to this question. Both the first level and second level support people admitted they could not find the answer to this question. ??

The REST API is documented at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations.

Note that for each API endpoint there is a line that looks to me like a permissions value. For example for the "get messages" API there is:
"Required scope: Mail.Read". For the send message there is: "Required scope: Mail.Send" and for delete message there is: "Required scope: Mail.ReadWrite". Simple straight forward stuff.

I'm accessing my personal email for the company I work for and I am able to, via the aforementioned REST API's, send messages and fetch messages; NO PROBLEM. When I attempt to delete a message, the response is 403; Forbidden.

Assuming that my account has not been granted the correct permission for delete: Mail.ReadWrite, I contacted the Office 365 administrator at my company and requested that he review the permissions granted to my account and to grant me Mail.ReadWrite. He agreed that this must be the issue.

However, his training had not prepared him for this request. He didn't know how to do it. So, he contacted MS support to to find out how he(as the sole administrator) could grant my account permission to be accessed by the REST API. And, like I mentioned above, the ms people did not know how to administer this functionality.

I asked if there was an administrators guide ANYPLACE that would document this feature and the ms people didn't have a clue.

Anybody?

p.s. I'm accessing the api's with the python requests package.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the response in  more detail revealed this is the problem:

{"error":{"code":"OAuthMissingForThisService","message":"Authentication for this service requires OAuth: outlook.office.com."}}